# user control dock to bottom

Tags: wpf

I'm having an issue with the dock panel not docking my usercontrl to the bottom. Can anyone help me figure out why this is not docking to the bottom?

```
    <StackPanel>
<DockPanel Name="dockPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <uc:UserControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,30,0,0" Background="White" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Why are you putting your `DockPanel` inside a `StackPanel`?  You can just put the `DockPanel` inside the main `Grid`.

Comment: @norlando points out your problem, stack panel won't let content Fill, grid will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `StackPanel` that is wrapping you `DockPanel` with a `Grid` or move your `DockPanel`  to the main `Grid` of your form.